# ¿Cómo se llama a un método PUT de web api desde Volley?

Tags: c#, android-studio, asp.net-web-api, android-volley

Estoy haciendo un servicio web api con `mvc` y `c#`, y una aplicación para Android que consume el servicio con `Volley`.

Alguien puede decirme como llamar a un método del servicio web de tipo `PUT` desde `Volley`? Soy incapaz.

He probado con el metodo que genera de ejemplo (modificado un poco):

```
//PUT api/values/5

    public IHttpActionResult Put(int id,string value)
    {
    int j = id;
    string dato = value;
    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = id }, value);
    }
```

y en Android, esta es la ultima prueba que he hecho:

```
private void enviaDatos()
{
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    try {

        jsonObject.put("id", 5);
        jsonObject.put("value", "hola");
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String JsonURL = getString(R.string.servidor)+"/api/values/5";
    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.PUT,
            JsonURL,
            jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        showProgress(false);
                        //getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(miFragment).commit();
                        String id = response.getString("Id");
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"COMUNICACIÓN ENVIADA CORRECTAMENTE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Log.e("VOLLEY", "TRAMITE ID:"+id);
                        Fragment fragment = new PantallaInico();
                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenidoPrincipal, fragment).commit();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("VOLLEY", e.getMessage());
                        showProgress(false);
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR LISTENER:"+error.getMessage());
                    showProgress(false);
                }
            }
    );
    // Adds the JSON array request "arrayreq" to the request queue
    requestQueue.add(postRequest);
}
```

He probado a depurar el servicio, y las peticiones es que ni llegan (y es correcto, los otros métodos funcionan bien)

He probado a pasar `StringRequest` y nada, a pasar los parámetros en el header, tampoco, por la url tampoco

Alguien sabe que me falta?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de `JsonObjectRequest` debes utilizar `StringRequest`, así como enviar los parámetros en un objeto `HashMap<String, String>`, y de igual forma recomendaría que el procesamiento de la petición estuviera en un método aparte.

Definición de los parámetros a enviar y ejecución del método:

```
final Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
parameters.put("id", "5");
parameters.put("value", "hola");

ProcessRequest(parameters);
```

Definición del método que procesará la petición:

```
private void ProcessRequest(Map<String, String> parameters){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    try {
                        showProgress(false);
                        //getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(miFragment).commit();
                        String id = response.getString("Id");
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"COMUNICACIÓN ENVIADA CORRECTAMENTE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Log.e("VOLLEY", "TRAMITE ID:"+id);
                        Fragment fragment = new PantallaInico();
                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenidoPrincipal, fragment).commit();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("VOLLEY", e.getMessage());
                        showProgress(false);
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR LISTENER:"+error.getMessage());
                    showProgress(false);
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return parameters;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Por el lado del WebApi de MVC, no creo que tengas que realizar ningún cambio, ya que comentas que estás utilizando el se crea por *default*.

Para probar cómo se está generando la petición puedes utilizar la consola de Android, y para hacer una prueba aparte del API recomiendo que uses algún programa de un tercero como [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), pero, si los quieres probar en conjunto, debes poner la URL que te genera Visual Studio con su respectivo puerto y tener corriendo ambos proyectos.

#### Actualización

- Se corrige el código para consumir el API por método `PUT`
- Dado que has ejecutado el API con el método `PUT` y te ha marcado el error **HTTP - 405 *Method not allowed*** (método no permitido), esto significa que intentas consumir un API por método `PUT` pero por *default* tiene configurado `GET` a menos que lo declares explicítamente en el `Action`. Para corregir esto, faltaría realizar una configuración en el API para que también tenga ese método/verbo declarado como `PUT` poniendo en el `Action`  `[HttpPut]`:

  ```
  [HttpPut]
  public IHttpActionResult Put(int id,string value)
  {
      int j = id;
      string dato = value;
      return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = id }, value);
  }
  ```

Comment: He probado lo que me has dicho, pero no funciona.

Cuando lo ejecuto, no llama al metodo Put (que en teoria es para editar), si no que llama al metodo Post.

Si cambio la linea
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,....
por 
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT,....

Entonces obtego el mismo error 405

Alguna idea?

Comment: @Juanjo tienes razón, debe ir por método `PUT`, he corregido el código y además agregado una configuración en el API para que te funcione de manera adecuada :D

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Lo he estado probando, pero no me funciona. Me he dado cuenta, que es un problema de Web Api, que continuamente devuelve el error 405. hasta me he creado una aplicación de escritorio para probar el web api y no va. Sabes como solucionarlo?

Comment: @Juanjo sí, justo con la segunda parte que puse en la respuesta, con eso se compone :D